# Asking for user input in print function - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, printing

Sorry if this seems like a bit of a dumb question but I’m a bit confused about a Python 2 exercise I am trying to complete.

The exercise asks to write a code that will find the factorial of a number.

I have written a function that does this but I am confused about the pre set print function that has asks for user input as I’ve only seen this done as a separate thing. Could anyone help me figure out how to make this work please as the exercise asks for the print function to not be deleted.

Thank you in advance!

```
def FirstFactorial(num):

  # code goes here
  fact = 1
  while num > 0:
    fact *= num
    num -= 1
  return fact

x = raw_input("enter a number: ")
result = FirstFactorial(x)
# keep this function call here
print FirstFactorial(raw_input())
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `print result` not `print FirstFactorial(raw_input())`

The way it is set up now the program will work for the first input, but it will never print it out so you never see `result`.

Then it will look for a second input from your second call to `raw_input()`, but the user will not be notified that the program wants a second input. The second output of FirstFactorial() will be correctly printed.

Comment: Is there a way I could change it in order to keep the last function call as that one was provided by the exercise?

Comment: @PedroSilva You could remove the first `raw_input()` and `FirstFactorial()` calls, then you should add a parameter to the second `raw_input()` which will be the message that asks the user for an input. So you can remove lines 10 and 11 and change line 13 to say: `print FirstFactorial(raw_input("Enter a number: "))`